# Yii:Framework - Finding table with multiple related categories from $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, relationships

I use this Yii code in my controller to search after POST

```
$model = Questions::model()->with( 
  array( 
    'categories' => array (
      'select' => 'name',
      'condition' => 'categories.id=:cat_id',
      'params' => array (':cat_id' => $_POST["Questions"]["categories"])
    ),
    'countries' => array (
      'select' => 'name',
      'condition' => 'countries.id=:cou_id',
      'params' => array (':cou_id' => $_POST["Questions"]["countries"])
    ) 
  )
)->findAll(array('select' => 'question'));
```

This is ok until all data in POST is not an array.

I want to change POST to return an array. Now, when I return from view a $_POST['Questions']['categories'] as an array how do I write the criteria for Questions::model().

I get Notice:

```
Array to string conversion: this->_statement->bindValue($name, $value, $this->_connection->getPdoType(gettype($value)));
```

So, what is a correct way to do it ? :)

-- The code for the post ( from the view )

```
CHtml::activeCheckboxList($model, 'countries'CHtml::listData(Countries::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'), array('template'=>'<li>{input} {label}</li>',));
$form->dropDownList($model, 'categories', 
                  CHtml::listData(Categories::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
                  array('prompt' => 'Select category')
            );
```

if u need more info there is also my previous post, this is a continuation [see post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764882/yii-framework-help-to-translate-relational-sql-query)

Comment: can you post code that post values

Comment: yeah, i just did edited the code. Hope is that what u meant. Basically is very simple one categories now are an array from multiple check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not that good with joins, but I would try something like:

```
$model = Questions::model()->with( 
  array( 
    'categories' => array (
      'select' => 'name',
    ),
    'countries' => array (
      'select' => 'name',
      'condition' => 'countries.id=:cou_id',
      'params' => array (':cou_id' => $_POST["Questions"]["countries"])
    ) 
  )
)->findAllByAttributes(
    array('categories.id' => $_POST["Questions"]["categories"]), 
    array('select' => 'question'));
```

Although I don't think this will return what you want it to.